# How to solve System.Web.HttpException: is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am on developing a website using **ASP.Net** (VB.net), @ particular phase Execute the following code to

```
Private Sub btndownload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndownload.Click
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
   Response.TransmitFile(hdndownload.Value) ' http:/localhost/sample_web/sample.pdf is the value for hdndownload.Value
End Sub
```

But it result in error as follows:

```
Server Error in '/sample_web' Application.
http://localhost/sample_web/sample.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: 'http:/localhost/sample_web/sample.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.
```

Comment: It should be http://... not http:/...

Comment: the path (http://..) was default generated on error message, see the question it is spelled correctly in the input

Answer (score 1):

If the value in your comment for hdndownload.value is correct you ars missing a /

the value being passed should be

```
http://localhost/sample_web/sample.pdf 
      ^
```

not

```
http:/localhost/sample_web/sample.pdf
```